# Pagination for Pages and Posts

Tags: posts, pages, pagination

I want to use Pagination throughout a new theme but am having trouble getting it to work correctly.

I am using some code within my functions.php file and then calling that function. It works on the 'blog' page but not on paginated posts or pages.

Here is my code:

```
// Pagination for paged posts, Page 1, Page 2, Page 3, with Next and Previous Links, No plugin
function canvas_pagination()
{
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999;
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'type' => 'list'
    ));
}

add_action('init', 'canvas_pagination'); // Add our Pagination
```

And call the funtion: `<?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>`

This code works great within the index.php file.
See here: http://website-test-lab.com/sites/blank_canvas/blog/

But not within single.php and page.php:

- SITE URL + /paginated/
- SITE URL + /page-pagination/
  (*Can't add more than 2x links here*)

Can someone explain why this doesn't work and what needs to be amended to fix it.

I have tried using wp_link_pages but it's not giving me the ability to customise the output I require.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Post Navigation**

Here's the way its done in the Twenty Twelve themes single.php file however it looks like Twenty Fourteen has a better solution which works for pages as well.

```
<nav class="nav-single">
                <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h3>
                <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span> %title' ); ?></span>
                <span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>' ); ?></span>
            </nav><!-- .nav-single -->
```

You could hook this code in from your functions file using a theme specific hook or filtering the WordPress content hook.

There's some good [examples of using the content filter in your functions file here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content).

More http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links

**Page Navigation**

[Here's a tutorial i wrote](http://wpsites.net/web-design/conditional-archive-page-navigation-for-any-theme/) which uses the code from Twenty Fourteen theme.

It creates a template tag you can use in a custom function with hook and conditional tags or directly in a template file.

Comment: Thanks. Not quite what I was looking for but will look into the 2014 theme to see if that will help.

Comment: I think what I need is wp_link_pages, customised.

Comment: I think what you need are 2 functions. One for posts and one for archive pagination. Both of which you'll find in Twenty Fourteen or any other default theme.

Comment: Was this question ever resolved?

Answer (score -1):

Step:1 Make Function in function.php

```
<?php    
function vb_pagination( $query=null ) { 
  global $wp_query;
  $query = $query ? $query : $wp_query;
  $big = 999999999; 

  $paginate = paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'type' => 'array',
'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
)
 ); 

 if ($query->max_num_pages > 1) :
?>
<ul class="pagination">
  <?php
  foreach ( $paginate as $page ) {
    echo '<li>' . $page . '</li>';
  }
  ?>
</ul>
<?php
  endif;
}
```

Step : 2 call the pagination function require to use

```
<?php if ( function_exists('vb_pagination') ) {
                    vb_pagination( $the_query );
                } ?>
```

Comment: Please clean up your post and remove plain text from the code block. As it stands, you whole post is in one big code block

Comment: Downvoted due to your code being really messy after I have asked you to clean it up